# Tsc crashes with aws

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-sdk-js

Im trying to compile ts code into javascript with tsc. But it keep crashing on aws code from node_modules. I was trying to add `skipLibCheck` into my tsconfig, adding empty array to `types` property in tsconfig and add node_modules path into `exclude` property but it didn't help.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "exclude": ["./node_modules/**"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [],
    /* Basic Options */
    "incremental": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "build",
    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    /* Additional Checks */
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    /* Experimental Options */
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    /* Advanced Options */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
}
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.15.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^9.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "http-status-codes": "^2.1.4",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "sequelize": "^6.6.2",
    "sequelize-typescript": "^2.1.0",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.6",
    "tsoa": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tsoa/runtime": "^3.6.1",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.10",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/helmet": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.5",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.37",
    "@types/swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.2",
    "@types/validator": "^13.1.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.22.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.22.0",
    "concurrently": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  }
```

sample error

```
$ tsc
node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/protocols/Aws_restXml.ts:14525:34 - error TS6133: 'tagName' is declared but its value is never read.

14525         tagValueProcessor: (val, tagName) => (val.trim() === "" ? "" : decodeEscapedXML(val)),
                                       ~~~~~~~


Found 132 errors.
```

Comment: The reference exclude path in the documentation is described as `node_modules` not `node_modules/**` and the reference for targeting a file in a directory is given as `src/**/*` (note the final asterisk). Does removing the two asterisks have any effect? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: @cefn same results w/o asterisks

Comment: ...and tsconfig is in the same folder as node_modules ?

Comment: @cefn yes it is

Comment: Have you managed to get any result?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone reaches into this one, solution for me was to upgrade ts to v4